# Integral of cosine to fractional exponent

Tags: integration

I would like to solve the following integral analytically:

$$\int_0^T\left|\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  t}{T}\right)\right|^{n+1} dt$$

where $0<n<1$ and $t$ is variable. Cosine is in absolute value. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is it absolute value ?

Comment: Yes, it is absolute value.

Comment: Is this post related to homework ? What did you try ?

Comment: As a first step, get rid of the absolute value by noting that your integral runs over one period of cosine. By the symmetry of cosine, the integral equals $4\int_0^{T/4}\cos(2\pi t/T)^{n+1}\,dt$. Then, you could also do $u=2\pi t/T$ to get rid of unnecessary constants in the integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of $$ \int_0^T \left| \cos\left( \frac{2\pi t}{T} \right) \right|^{n+1} dt $$ 
By using the symmetry of cosine we get:
$$ \int_0^T \left| \cos\left( \frac{2\pi t}{T} \right) \right|^{n+1} dt = 4\int_0^{\frac{T}{4}} \left( \cos\left( \frac{2\pi t}{T} \right) \right)^{n+1} dt $$
By setting $$ x = \frac{2\pi t}{T} $$
the integral takes the following form:
$$ \frac{2T}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \cos\left( x \right) \right)^{n+1} dx $$
By using the Wallis Cosine Formula http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WallisCosineFormula.html

$$ \frac{2T}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \cos\left( x \right) \right)^{n+1} dx = \frac{2T}{\sqrt{\pi}(n+1)}\ \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}(n+2) \right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}(n+1) \right)} $$

where $ \Gamma () $ is the gamma function. The solution is:

$$ \int_0^T \left| \cos\left( \frac{2\pi t}{T} \right) \right|^{n+1} dt   = \frac{2T}{\sqrt{\pi}(n+1)}\ \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}(n+2) \right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}(n+1) \right)} $$

for $$ n>-1 $$

I have checked against numerical solutions and it works fine!
Thank you all very much for the contribution!!!!

Answer (score 1):

With the definite integral (e.g. from Wolfram Alpha, see also [Wallis Cosine Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WallisCosineFormula.html) for integer $n$)
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos x^{n+1} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\Gamma(n/2+1)}{\Gamma(n/2+3/2)}, \quad \Re(n) > -2$$
and the fact that you integrate over the full period, i.e. four quarter periods, you get with the symmetries of $\cos$

$$\int_0^T\left|\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  t}{T}\right)\right|^{n+1} dt$$
$$=\frac{T}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\cos x\right|^{n+1} dt$$
$$=4\frac{T}{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\left|\cos x\right|^{n+1} dt$$
$$=4\frac{T}{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos x^{n+1} dt$$
$$=4\frac{T}{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\Gamma(n/2+1)}{\Gamma(n/2+3/2)}$$
$$=\frac{T}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n/2+1)}{\Gamma(n/2+3/2)}$$